# Yii2: REST API actions in ActiveController

Tags: php, json, rest, yii2

In docs guides there is example:

```
    namespace app\controllers;

    use yii\rest\ActiveController;

    class UserController extends ActiveController
    {
        public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

But i dont get it, how to work with actions.

For example:

- **DataBase** has tables with many-to-many relationship (via Junction table).
- **Сomponent** to work with the models and the formation of a common response from multiple tables according to the transmitted data. Can return an array, or an array of objects.

When use it in commands controller, it was like:

```
    class LastTweetsController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @param int $count
         *
         * @throws yii\base\InvalidConfigException
         */
        public function actionIndex($count = 10)
        {
            /** @var TweetLastfinder $tweetLastFinder */
            $tweetLastFinder = Yii::$app->get('tweetlastfinder');

            /**
             * @var TweetShow $tweetShow
             */
            $tweetShow = Yii::$app->get('tweetshow');

            // For show tweets into terminal:
$tweetShow->showLastTweetsJSON($tweetLastFinder->findLastTweets($count));
        }
    }
```

But how i can make same operation in ActiveController (Transmit parameter $count and return result in JSON)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change API's default actions like - create,update,view,index,delete
write below code in controller

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';

   /* Declare actions supported by APIs (Added in api/modules/v1/components/controller.php too) */
    public function actions(){
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['create']);
        unset($actions['update']);
        unset($actions['delete']);
        unset($actions['view']);
        unset($actions['index']);
        return $actions;
    }

    /* Declare methods supported by APIs */
    protected function verbs(){
        return [
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH','POST'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
            'view' => ['GET'],
            'index'=>['GET'],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex($count = 10){
        /** @var TweetLastfinder $tweetLastFinder */
        $tweetLastFinder = Yii::$app->get('tweetlastfinder');

        /**
         * @var TweetShow $tweetShow
         */
        $tweetShow = Yii::$app->get('tweetshow');

        // This will return in JSON:
        return $tweetLastFinder->findLastTweets($count);
    }
}
```

In API main config file -

```
    'components' => [  
        ....
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                 [
                        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                        'controller' => 'v1/user',
                        'tokens' => [
                            '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>',
                            '{count}' => '<count:\\w+>', 
                        ],
                        //'pluralize' => false,
                        'extraPatterns' => [    
                            'POST' => 'create', // 'xxxxx' refers to 'actionXxxxx'
                            'PUT {id}' => 'update',
                            'PATCH {id}' => 'update',
                            'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
                            'GET {id}' => 'view',
                            'GET {count}' => 'index',
                        ],

                    ],
            ]
        ],
        ....
    ]
```

In your case you want $count in index action parameter so in url manager you need to define 'count' token just like 'id'

Comment: Thanks, before i close the issue, kindly ask you to a bit explain of this code. Also  how i can transmit the paramaeter $count and actionIndex return array which prepared in component...not json. How should be correctly done that json was in response.

Comment: My bad, i found the answer) tks

Comment: Many thanks. I still have question how to use component response in default action, but i already ask it in another question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309034/yii2-how-to-use-component-in-activecontroller-default-action