# Yii2: how to use component in ActiveController default action

Tags: php, rest, controller, yii2

As docs say:
`[[yii\rest\IndexAction|index]]: list resources page by page`

response has view:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://192.168.100.5/index.php/tweets"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 12:10:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 450
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 23
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20
Link: <http://192.168.100.5/tweets?page=1>; rel=self, <http://192.168.100.5/tweets?page=2>; rel=next, <http://192.168.100.5/tweets?page=23>; rel=last
Content-Length: 4305
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

[{"id":71,"text":"Juíza do RS Graziela Bünd.......
```

I have component which one return - some array (selection from two tables).  If i customize indexAction.

```
  public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['update']);
        unset($actions['delete']);
        unset($actions['view']);
       unset($actions['index']);

        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionIndex($count = 10)
    {
        /** @var TweetLastfinder $tweetLastFinder */
        $tweetLastFinder = Yii::$app->get('tweetlastfinder');

        return $tweetLastFinder->findLastTweets($count);
    }
```

Response have correct content but has view:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://192.168.100.5/index.php/tweets"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 12:15:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Content-Length: 2282
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

[{"id":605,"text":"Popular Mus......
```

In this case i cant use `$serializer`, show `_meta` etc

I want to use response from component and list resources page by page as it do default action. How it should be done properly?

Answer (score 1):

To get full use of the built in [yii\rest\Serializer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-serializer.html) and show `_meta` or have your urls to look like:

```
/tweets?page=5&per-page=12&sort=name
```

your action should return a [data provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#data-providers) object that implements the [DataProviderInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-dataproviderinterface.html) which can be any of those:

- an [Active Data
  Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#active-data-provider)
- [SQL Data
  Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#sql-data-provider)
- an [Array Data
  Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#array-data-provider)
- or a [Custom Data
  Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#custom-data-provider)

So it all depends on what kind of object `$tweetLastFinder->findLastTweets()` is returning. If the `findLastTweets` method is returning an `ActiveQuery` object like:

```
public function findLastTweets($count)
{
    ...
    return $Tweets::find();
}
```

Then just put it into an `ActiveDataProvider` instance:

```
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

public function actionIndex($count = 10)
{
    /** @var TweetLastfinder $tweetLastFinder */
    $tweetLastFinder = Yii::$app->get('tweetlastfinder');

    $tweets = $tweetLastFinder->findLastTweets();

    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $tweets,
    ]);
}
```

If it returns an array of data or something you can convert to an array then just put it into an `ArrayDataProvider` instance. If it is a more complex object then you'll need to build a custom Data Provider inside which you can wrap it. See how to do that in related [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#custom-data-provider).

Comment: Hmm.. i dont get it,  why in default action able to use simple url? Is action in you answer is customized? Do you mean that i need to unset `index`?

Comment: no not url just a direct call to class without declaring its namespace `use \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider` in top of file. I'll do an update to explain better.

Comment: updated. Note that `$count` won't make sense here as the Serializer will take care from there to filter and limit data. you will just need to set `&per-page=xx` in your request.

Comment: Many thanks. But in all cases `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`, What have i do wrong?

Comment: 500 is general. it can be anything even missing `;`. usually shown instead of the real error message by your server when display_errors is disabled in php.ini (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)). the real error message can also be found in your server's log files.

Comment: did you add `use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;` or whatever else provider namespace in top of your file ?

Comment: yes i do. Idea dont let me use new ActiveDataProvider without it.